# INSERTing into mysql table for user relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, normalization

I have a table for many-to-many relationship of users (three columns: relationship_id, user_id, user_id). How can I keep the relationships unique when the table accepts any entry? When I have a row of
`22 11 43`
How can I prevent INSERT of next_id `11 43` and more importantly next_id `43 11`? When user 11 requested relationship with user 43, user 43 must not be able to request relationship with user 11.

How can I check two columns before INSERT?

And my problem is even more serious as I have two tables (request and relationships). A row from request table will be deleted and inserted into relationships upon user approval. The reason for using two tables is that many pending requests make the table so long, which should be used regularly for displaying user friends.

When INSERTing request from user 11 to user 43, what is the fastest and efficient method to check for possible existence of `11 43` and `43 11` rows in tables: requests and relationships?

Comment: Please don't open new topics for the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104956/how-to-join-two-fks-from-a-table-to-another-table

Comment: @wildplasser these are different topics, one is about the table structure and how to INSERT, and one is how to use JOIN to read the table (if not changing the table structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime I have used a ***"Linking Table"*** to keep track of many to many relationships I always **DELETE** any existing relationships before **INSERTING** the new relationships. However, this may not work in your case because your linking table contains the surrogate key relationship_id. If you drop the surrogate key from the linking table and use a stored procedure you can do every thing you listed.

#### Identifying Duplicates

Create a **View** using **CASE** logic

`CREATE VIEW vFriendRequests
AS
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN ID_1 < ID_2 THEN ID_1
  ELSE ID_2
END CASE as RequestId_1,
CASE
  WHEN ID_1 < ID_2 THEN ID_2
  ELSE ID_1
END CASE as RequestId_2
FROM Friend_Requests_Table`

Then you can do a select distinct from this view to get only the unique sets of requests.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options to achieve what you want (which to choose or combine depends mainly on your datamodel, client architecture and storage engine):

- create a [unique composite](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) [`index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html) on both `user_id` columns
- revoke `INSERT` into `relationships` and implement a Stored Procedure for `INSERT` (this can do any checks etc. you want) OR implement an [ON BEFORE INSERT trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) which does what you want
- IF the the order of the `user_id`s is not relevant change the `INSERT` code to always sort both `ID`s before `INSERT`ing (for example via the Stored Procedure approach)
  This way you don't need to check explicitely but the index will do all work for you
- create a fourth column `idcomb` in `relationships` with a `UNIQUE INDEX` and an `ON BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` which just takes both `user_id` sorts them and concatenates them with a `-` inbetween and assign that to `idcomb` column as value... this way all work is done by the index and no change on the client-side is needed (when some duplicate is inserted is just comes back with an error)