# How to JOIN two FKs from a table to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, normalization, inner-join

I have a table of many-to-many relationships as:

Table `relationship`:

```
relationship_id,
first_user REFERENCES users(user_id),
second_user REFERENCES users(user_id),
```

Table `users`:

```
user_id,
other user information
```

To read friends of a given user (which can be in `first_user` or `second_user`), I need to JOIN two tables (`relationships` and `users`), but two columns of the table `relationships` are FK

**Question 1:** How can I JOIN two tables to use both FKs?

I have a table for pending requests which is similar to the table `relationships`. Upon approving a request, it will be deleted from `requests` and INSERTed into `relationships`.

**Question 2:** How can I JOIN three tables to retrieve connection and pending requests in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to give the instances of the "users" table aliases, so you can refer to them serparately:

```
SELECT u1.*, u2.* FROM relationship r
  JOIN users u1 ON (u1.user_id = r.first_user)
  JOIN users u2 ON (u2.user_id = r.second_user)
```

To select both from requests and relationships, you can use a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

```
SELECT u1.*, u2.* FROM relationship r
  JOIN users u1 ON (u1.user_id = r.first_user)
  JOIN users u2 ON (u2.user_id = r.second_user)
UNION
SELECT u1.*, u2.* FROM requests r
  JOIN users u1 ON (u1.user_id = r.first_user)
  JOIN users u2 ON (u2.user_id = r.second_user)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use both foreign keys, you need two joins (one for each):

```
select * 
  from relationship r 
 inner join users u1 on (u1.user_id = r.first_user)
 inner join users u2 on (u2.user_id = r.second_user)
```

Answer (score 1):

The {relationship_id, first_user, second_user} table contains a **repeating group**.

Just remove one of them (that makes relationship_id non-unique) and add a surrogate key (or add userid to the primary key).

```
CREATE TABLE relationships
( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, relationship_id INTEGER NOT NULL
, user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

It would be a nice homework assignment to try to generate constraints for this construct.

Another way (for binary relations like marriages) is to put the "significant Other" link in the users table:

```
 CREATE TABLE lusers
 ( luser_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 , magnificent_other INTEGER REFERENCES lusers (luser_id)
 ...
 );
```

As a side effect, this will also make bigamy impossible.
Again: nice homework assignment to implement the constraints.